# Motion can't find wireless camera

Tags: motion

I'm using motion on the raspberry pi and setting it up for the first time.  It can't find my Foscam wireless camera, and it persists in trying to open `/dev/video0` even though I have that video device commented out in the config file.  I know my camera url is correct because I can reach it through a browser.  I've researched this extensively but can't find anyone that is using a wifi networked ip camera.

Here's the output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo motion
[0] Processing thread 0 - config file /etc/motion/motion.conf
[0] Motion 3.2.12 Started
[0] ffmpeg LIBAVCODEC_BUILD 3482368 LIBAVFORMAT_BUILD 3478785
[0] Thread 1 is from /etc/motion/motion.conf
[0] motion-httpd/3.2.12 running, accepting connections
[0] motion-httpd: waiting for data on port TCP 8080
[1] Thread 1 started
[1] Failed to open video device /dev/video0: No such file or directory
[1] Could not fetch initial image from camera
[1] Motion continues using width and height from config file(s)
[1] Resizing pre_capture buffer to 1 items
[1] Started stream webcam server in port 8081
[1] Retrying until successful connection with camera
[1] Failed to open video device /dev/video0: No such file or directory
[1] Retrying until successful connection with camera
[1] Failed to open video device /dev/video0: No such file or directory
[1] Retrying until successful connection with camera
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured this out.  I had accidentally left a line commented out.

Comment: Adding the specific line would improve your answer.